# python logging kwarg failing when passed thru the args section

Tags: python, logging

I have the following file configuration section :

```
[handler_file]
class = handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler
args = ( '../output/DataUpload.log', when='D', backupCount=3)
formatter = generic
```

As specified by logging.config

```
from logging import config, getLogger
config.fileConfig( "config/logging.cfg", disable_existing_loggers = True )
```

And I get the following error :

```
  args = eval(args, vars(logging))
  File "<string>", line 1
    ( '../output/DataUpload.log', when='D', backupCount=3)
                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Are kwargs not supported here or am I doing something wrong ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First off, **don't use eval(), it's a very bad idea!!** Use ConfigParser or JSON or something to store and load a config.

As for the error:

```
args = (...,)
```

This creates a *tuple*. A tuple cannot have named elements. You want to use a tuple or list for the positional arguments, and a dict for named arguments. If you use JSON for the config file, you'll get this.

Comment: I am using the config file as specified by logging.config (I have edit'ed the original question) - nothing new that I have created and I am not using eval anywhere. Do you mean I should not use the logging.config and that is not bad idea ? Thanks Colin.

Comment: +1 You cannot use `logging.config` to pass keyword arguments [source reference](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/29bdbcadf299/Lib/logging/config.py#l155)

Comment: @TokenMacGuy your comment is the actual answer.

Answer (score 0):

In python, you can specify `kwargs` through the `args` variable if you get the order of parameters correct. This makes things a bit less reliable if the method signature changes (ie: through later python versions).

Python 3.10.4 has a RotatingFileHandler class signature of

```
RotatingFileHandler(filename, mode='a', maxBytes=0, backupCount=0, encoding=None, delay=False, errors=None)
```

Every `*args` argument that goes over the required number will auto-fill the kwargs.

Let's say you want to only set the `backupCount`. If using `*args` to set it, you need to fill each kwarg up until that specific one.

```
[handler_file_handler]
class=logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=formatter
args=('%(log_path)s', "a", 10000, 3,)
```

There is no way to only specify `backupCount` without setting `mode` and `maxBytes` due to the order.